# ¿Cómo modificamos una variable de una clase base pasándola por diferentes herencias?

Tags: c++

Saludos a toda la comunidad.

Tengo un problema, que seguro que la solucion es de las mas sencillas pero llevo varios dias intentando sacarlo adelante.

Simplemente tengo una clase principal A, y de ella derivan dos clases, B y C.

La intencion es que... B coge un valor de A, lo modifica y se lo devuelve y C toma ese valor actualizado y lo modifica y se lo devuelve.

El problema, es que C siempre coge el valor incial de A y no el actualizado por B.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class A {
public:
    int x = 10;

    void mostrarValorX() {
        cout << "El valor de x es... " << x << endl;
    }
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    int sumaraA() {

        return x = x + 10;
    }
};


class C : public A
{
public:
    int sumarOtraVez()
    {
        return x = x + 20;
    }

};


int main()
{

    A objectoA;
    objectoA.mostrarValorX();

    B objetoB;
    objetoB.sumaraA();
    objetoB.mostrarValorX();

    C objetoC;
    objetoC.sumarOtraVez();
    objetoC.mostrarValorX(); 
}
´´´
```

Answer (score 2):

El resultado del código es el correcto. No es una cuestión de herencia, la herencia está funcionando bien. Lo que tienes que tener en cuenta es que `x` es una variable miembro de la clase, y cada uno de los objetos que creas tiene una `x` interna que es independiente a la de los otros. Si quieres que exista una sola variable que sea modificable por todas las instancias de la clase, debes crear una variable estática:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class A {
public:
    static int x;

    void mostrarValorX() {
        cout << "El valor de x es... " << x << endl;
    }
};

int A::x = 10;


class B : public A
{
public:
    int sumaraA() {

        return x = x + 10;
    }
};


class C : public A
{
public:
    int sumarOtraVez()
    {
        return x = x + 20;
    }

};


int main()
{

    A objectoA;
    objectoA.mostrarValorX();

    B objetoB;
    objetoB.sumaraA();
    objetoB.mostrarValorX();

    C objetoC;
    objetoC.sumarOtraVez();
    objetoC.mostrarValorX(); 
}
```

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de que respondiste 4 minutos antes

Answer (score 1):

> El problema, es que C siempre coge el valor incial de A y no el actualizado por B.

`A`, `B` y `C` son clases. Las variables miembro que declaras en las clases no son comunes a todos los objetos que construyas, sino que cada objeto tendrá su propia colección de variables miembro.

Si quieres compartir una variable entre todas las instancias de un objeto tienes que usar el modificador `static`:

```
class A {
public:
    static int x;
};

int A::x = 10;
```

Usar `static` tiene otra implicación en tu caso, y es que no puedes inicializarla al momento de declararla.

En cualquier caso esta solución dista mucho de ser elegante. Es, de hecho, una solución muy restrictiva, pues te impide crear dos objetos `A` con valores diferentes.

Probablemente, si aportas más información acerca del objetivo que pretendes conseguir, se pueda afinar más la respuesta